# use case diagram clarification - showing relationships between use cases

Tags: diagram, use-case

I was asked to draw **a use case diagram** for a fuel filling station (**five use cases** at minimum). The diagram should show all relationships between the use cases.

Does it mean I have to only draw **ONE use case diagram**, which includes **FIVE use cases** in the diagram??

Like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShsTa.png

Comment: Nothing to do with programming

Comment: Why are you asking us, instead of requesting clarification from whoever had you make the diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, five use cases are totally fine for one diagram. They should easily fit on one chart, also when including their relationships and the actors. Since it is one system that you describe, why split up? When you exceed 10 use cases, consider generalization or splitting them up into >1 diagram.

Rule of thumb: Make it fit printed on an A4 page.